# Question incorrectly stated as answer and vice versa

Tags: bug, review

Is there something up with the review queue today? In the text it mentions `first question` but it is really an answer.

[image: Text says first question but it is an answer]

Or it mentions `first answer` when it is really a question.

[image: Text says first answer but it is a question]